# Unpaid medical bill - Collection Notice

Tags: credit-score, debt-collection, billing

I do not have any debt in the past 10 years in US. I have good credit score 715+. This has been the case from the beginning. Of late, I had a minor medical emergency and my insurance paid some amount and medical office sent another bill for $250. (yes, its not a big amount). But I doubt this is too high for the treatment done (Just a band-aid for burns and prescription). However, I was not in town and its been more than 3 months. I completely forgot amidst other things. I got a collection notice to pay the amount in 30 days.

Should I just ignore this or pay the amount? Though its not a big amount, I feel they are trying to pull more money.

If I ignore, how does it affect my credit score and how long will that appear on my Credit Report?

If I pay off that amount, will that have again some effect on my Credit Score?

Comment: Wait, are you saying that the bill is incorrect in some way? That they are double billing you for the same service?

Comment: Over billing for the service!

Comment: What I'm asking is whether it is a legitimate charge, or you just think it was too expensive.

Comment: Its too expensive for the service provided.

Comment: In that case I'd say pay it. It sucks, but you can't exactly negotiate after you have been provided the service.

Comment: I pricked my finger on a rusty nail. Went for a tetanus shot. Nurse gave me the shot and bandaide. They said a doctor was coming to check me out. I tried to run out but he walked into the room, $200 to walk in. He literally did nothing. The nurse gave me the shot. $350 total. $50 for serum, $100 nurse, and $200 for the doctor. So, yes, I feel your pain.

Comment: A little off topic, but in the future you should discuss costs up front.  A number of things, especially small ones, are much cheaper to just pay cash at the time of treatment.  You'll want to discuss this prior to presenting any insurance information.

Comment: Even now it may not be too late. Talk to the healthcare provider and tell them you think it's too much. tell them it isn't covered by insurance. You may be able to negotiate a reduction. However what it sounds like is that $250 is the deductible on a bill that is partly covered by insurance. If so then you just have to pay up. Is that the case?

Comment: No, its not deductible. Insurance covered some amount, its in  addition to what insurance covered for that procedure/treatment. I talked to them and they reduced 20%. I paid the $200 to close the account with them. I again think they charged much. As others suggested here, its better to pay $200 bucks than its affecting my Credit rating (Though I do not have any EMIs to pay other than Rent or any plans to buy things as of now), which might cost me $1000s.

Comment: @JoeTaxpayer: That's when I would have told them I'm not paying it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This can create a black mark on your report that can be far more costly than the $250.

A debate over 'fair or reasonable' isn't on topic here. I am simply offering you the fact that  in a few years, you might be charged 1/8% more on a loan, and that may cost you thousands.

In response to the comment/question below, when I went to CreditKarma and asked for a score simulation if I had a default on my record, I got this:

[image]

a 32 point drop.

Comment: Thanks for the input. Do you know how much does this affect to score? Currently, lets say I have 715

Comment: This is a practical answer, but shouldn't the real answer be that you should pay it because it is the ethical thing to do?

Comment: @JohnFx - perhaps. But had I answered with only that, I'd be voted down as not directly answering the question. OP didn't ask right or wrong, but how it would impact his score.

Comment: @JoeTaxpayer That was more directed at OP than you. This is a good answer based on what was asked.